# Redirect DB traffic dependent on type of request

Tags: utilities, postgresql, cluster

I have a Postgres cluster managed by Patroni and want to be able to redirect DB requests to the replica if they are read requests and write requests to the master.
Does anyone know of any tools that could do this?
I looked at PGPOOL II but that looks like it does the same thing as Patroni.

Answer (score 0):

`SQL Relay` can do that

- check it out [here](http://sqlrelay.sourceforge.net/)